# Вернуть статус сервера

Tags: java, spark-framework

Как при обращении клиента к серверу вернуть ему статус сервера 200?
Используется spark. Нашел что можно сделать как то `response.status(200)`, но куда это писать и как должно работать не понял. Вот по этому url надо вернуть статус:

```
head("/url")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        head("/url", (req, res) -> {
            res.status(200);
            return "";
        });
    }
}
```

Только не пойму зачем делать это явно, 200-й статус устанавливается по умолчанию.